# Update color ramp after using Hue Saturation

Tags: node-editor

Is there a way to update the colors of the ramp after using Hue Saturation Value?

Maybe with a script?
I don't mind if the nodes are separated[image]

Comment: I don't quite understand what you are referring to by "updating the color ramp"...Could you elaborate?

Comment: Exactly like here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rdV25L3KPWg&feature=youtu.be      But will be changed only when i change Hue value from Hue Saturation Value

Comment: Normally if i put Hue Saturation Value node after color ramp, i can do it, but there is no way to make it updating the color in nodes.

What i want is a way to updating the colors inside nodes after i change them.